# Did the prep "gegenüber" use to use Genitiv oder Dativ in the past?

Tags: preposition, dative, genitive

[duden.de/gegenüber](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gegenueber_Praeposition) says the preposition «gegenüber» is followed by Dativ. I stood under the impression that it was followed by Genitiv in the past but found no mention of it in the respective article. Was it never used with Genitiv? Does someone know of a dictionary that suggested it's use with Genitiv?

Could it be that I am simply «hypercorrecting», like proposed by [Kilian Foth](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/2784/kilian-foth) in [another question with the same tags](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20372/pr%C3%A4positionen-mit-dem-dativ-genetiv)?

> «People using a genitive are simply wrong, possibly due to hypercorrection (the genitive is slowly being lost and replaced with the dative generally, so it happens that someone thinks a dative should really be a genitive even when it shouldn't).» - Kilian Foth

Comment: Asking *why* reasons in a language is generally not leading anywhere.

Comment: It should be used with Dativ only, but indeed you here it very often used with Genitiv, because natives don't know and/or speak dialect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*gegenüber* is one of the prepositions that rules the dative. Some Grammars (one [example](http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/gramwb.ansicht?v_app=&v_kat=gramm&v_buchstabe=G&v_id=2474)) claim it is also (rarely) used with the genitive.

Whether this is actually correct or an observation of hypercorrection (in my opinion, very likely) is maybe impossible to judge. Common usage, however, would be with dative.

[Grimms Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GG04561#XGG04561) has a bit of a rant on the french influence of *vis-a-vis*  on the usage of *gegenüber von* (the "french genitive") instead of *gegenüber* + dative. Other than that, I can find no historical trace that *gegenüber* has ever ruled the genitive.

Comment: Google n-grams agrees. The incidence of "...gegenüber des..." vs. "...gegenüber dem..." is negligible across all time periods.